# Replace check box with span element

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, checkbox

I was trying to style checkbox by using span with borders and hiding checkbox using css display property. When I run the above code snippet, it doesn't seem to work. I tried changing to `<p>` but it also didn't work. I want the span to stay red after I click. How can I achieve it by using css?  Here is my jsfiddle link.

> EDIT 1:

I want to replace a check box using a span.What i mean is i need the same behavior using span.When i click on span span color should change to red,when I click it again it should come to normal style,Like a check box checked and unchecked.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lwgv87ea/

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + span:hover{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
  }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
  }
input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #acacac;
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<label for="clothing_colors">
                  
                  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="Standing Collar"><span>Standing Collar</span>
</label>
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking to achieve? You want to click the box and have it stay red?

Comment: If your checkbox is hidden, it will not fire the :checked event as no click would register on it.

Comment: yes. I want it to stay red

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + span:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #acacac;
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="Standing Collar"><span>Standing Collar</span>

</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="3/4th Sleeves"><span>3/4th Sleeves</span>

</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="full sleeves"> <span>Full Sleeves</span>

</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="Sleeveless item"><span>Sleeveless item</span>

</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="Crop tops"><span>Crop Tops</span>

</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="Crop tops" class="clothing-type"><span class="clothing">Sheer Clothes</span>

</label>
</div>
```

You need to remove the `display:none` property from your css and add `visibility:hidden`
All your label have the same for attribute which make them not work.

Here is a correct implementation 
http://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/Lwgv87ea/2/

Comment: Well, display:none works with it too. My problem was that I had same name for label. Anyways, thanks for the answer. It works

Comment: Ohh, yes it should work with display:none as well. Didn't think about it. 
Good to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes are not being checked when you click on the span tags. Remove the display:none from your checkboxes and you'll see what I mean. You will need javascript to check the checkbox when you click the span element.

Comment: Is their a solution without jquery? Because i did the same with the radio buttons by using css but doesn't seem to work for checkbox

Comment: I don't want the checkbox, just the span elements in place of those checkbox

Comment: Check my answer.I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understood what is the role of check box over here.
But from your question what i understood is you want a span that behaves like a check box.
Check the below code snippet.

```js
$('.checkbox_span').click(function(){

$(this).toggleClass('check');

})
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + span:hover{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
  }

.check{
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
  }

input[type="checkbox"]{
  display:none;
  }
span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #acacac;
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="clothing_colors">
                  
                  <input type="checkbox" name="clothing-type" value="Standing Collar"/>
  <span class="checkbox_span">Standing Collar</span>
</label>
```